# How to launch shell command and generate JSON after Cplex OPL model runs?

Tags: javascript, shell, cplex, opl

I have an OPL model which solves an ILP.

Currently it writes the solution to a txt file.

I want to launch something on the completion of the model to nicely display the solution, so I need to run a shell command.

1. How can I launch an arbitrary shell command on completion of the OPL run?
2. Can I call a JavaScript file in the same project from the OPL run to process the data? (NOTE: I see I can do this with `includeScript(...)`)
3. Could I launch an arbitrary shell command within a JavaScript file?
4. I want to format the results as JSON. However the usual "JSON" object is not available within the Javascript context. Can I create an object in Javascript then "stringify" it as JSON?

(NOTE on (4) - the documentation claims that the JavaScript implementation is compliant with ECMA-262:

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.4.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/refjsopl/html/intro.html#1037020

However the ECMA-262 definition does include the `JSON.Stringify` function:

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.12

Why is it not then available in OPL?)

Answer (score 1):

Just some personal experience, OPLScript is incomplete if you treat it as a JavaScript variant - very incomplete. Every time I try to use some old-style JavaScript code in OPLScript, I re-learn this lesson.

At the very basic level, many standard array and object methods are missing. For example, you can't even use the `[]` syntax to create a JavaScript array or access the property of an object. You can't list the keys of an object, etc. ...

It's probably better to use another language such as Java or Python for any complex data structure (without re-inventing all the common facilities).

Answer (score 0):

1. This could be part of a new version if you re patient enough. But with 12.7.1 you could either use an external Java call from scripting or modify the example at `CPLEX_Studio1271\opl\examples\opl_interfaces\java\oplrunsample` in order to do what you need.
2. Yes through includes
3. Not in version 12.7.1
4. OPLscript is a subset of ECMA and not all functions are inside but you could manage with IloOplOutputFile See https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=a7738eaf-f053-4fa8-83dc-5886bc381244&ps=25